# How to display 4 rows from mysql database and then use a next button to show the next 4 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql

How to get this result in php

```
 php display page 1
1       kirk      12
2       JJ        45
3       smith     16
4       KK        50
```

```
 php display page 2
1       TT        12
2       kim       45
3       monique   16
4       PP        50
```

i am only getting the first 4 when i click the next button it bring back the first 4 again.
I want the next button to bring the next 4 and not the first 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display 4 rows from mysql database and then use a next button to show the next 4 in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085932/display-4-rows-from-mysql-database-and-then-use-a-next-button-to-show-the-next-4)

Answer (score 2):

`LIMIT [offset], [row_count]` so, `LIMIT 0,4` on the first page, `LIMIT 4,4` on the second page, `LIMIT 8,4` on the next, etc.

For more info, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

dev.mysql.com is generally a very good resource on syntax and general how-to.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want the webpage to stay, and just the table to change? In that case you will need to look at AJAX.

Comment: yes i want the webpage to stay and the table to change. I want to use php to do it.

Comment: You can't. PHP is a server-side scripting language. Once the HTML has been sent there is nothing you can do anymore. JavaScript can though, as it's also a client side language.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to make some way of letting the server know the current place you are in the pagination.  HTTP is a stateless protocol.  So something like query strings, hidden inputs, sessions, etc. will do you well.  Those are the things which create the illusion of a server remembering what you did last.

After you get that, then you're going to want to research the `LIMIT` keyword in MySQL.  That offers you what you need as far as parsing the results from the database.  LIMIT offers offsets, in addition to limits.

Without your question being more specific, I'm afraid my answer can't really be more specific.

Comment: i have some values in a database and i want to show 4 rows at a time using a next button on a single webpage. its like a search and the first 4 values is shown and then when the next button is clicked the next 4 result is shown